Can spark sql optimizer eliminate unnecessary joins?
It looks like spark sql unable to do this kind of optimization. Here's my sample code:
spark.sql("create temp view v1 as select t1.id as id, t2.id as id2, name, score, age from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id")
val result = spark.sql("select name from v1");
result.explain("extended")

In this sample code, the join can be eliminated, but query plan show that the join is still there, just wondering whether this join can be eliminated by spark sql optimizer? Attach the output of dataframe explain output:
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [name#4]
+- Join LeftOuter, (id#3L = id#11L)
   :- Project [id#3L, name#4]
   :  +- LogicalRDD [id#3L, name#4, score#5], false
   +- Project [id#11L]
      +- Filter isnotnull(id#11L)
         +- LogicalRDD [id#11L, age#12L], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Project [name#4]
+- SortMergeJoin [id#3L], [id#11L], LeftOuter
   :- *(2) Sort [id#3L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#3L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#44]
   :     +- *(1) Project [id#3L, name#4]
   :        +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#3L,name#4,score#5]
   +- *(4) Sort [id#11L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#11L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#49]
         +- *(3) Project [id#11L]
            +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(id#11L)
               +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[id#11L,age#12L]


How is it supposed to know that the join is supposed to be eliminated? It needs to know statistics about data, for example number of distinct values (NDV) or percentage of nulls in both tables. If the data source you use doesn't provide these statistics then spark has no way of knowing whether this join can be eliminated.

Which version spark? Should filter it out

Pls show outputs of explain.

Explain output is added

Odd to say the least
